# Elegant way to sort eloquent collection into alphabetical chunks

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to sort a collection from my database like this https://www.bodybuilding.com/store/listing.htm

I could write it, but I'd probably also lose the eloquent relationships which isn't ideal.

This feels like something Laravel something can do out of the box, or with very little logic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check into https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby to sort your collection. You'll probably have to add in a check for when the first letter changes in order to add a new header.

Comment: There isn't really an "out of the box" solution for `orderAndGroupByFirstLetter()` (which is what you're describing), but Laravel Collections, which is the result of a query, have a lot of methods available to handle this, such as `sortBy()`, `filter()`, `mapToGroups()`, etc. See if you can write something, and post a more specific question if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a model called `Categories` with a field `name` and you need to group the categories by the first letter of their name. Each category with a first letter that is not an alphabetic character will be grouped under the '#' symbol:

```
$collection = Categories::get();
$grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    $letter = $item->name[0];
    if (ctype_alpha($letter)) {
        return $letter;
    }
    return '#';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapToGroups` is what I was looking for. Here's my solution.

```
public function chunkByAlpha(Collection $collection)
{
    return $collection->mapToGroups(function($item, $key) {

        return ($this->isAlpha($item->name[0]) ? [strtoupper($item->name[0]) => $item] : ['#' => $item]);
    });
}

public function isAlpha($toCheck)
{
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $toCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an ordinary `foreach()` would suffice

```
$ordered = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $key = ctype_alpha($item->attribute[0]) ? $item->attribute[0] : 'other';
    $ordered[$item->attribute[0]][] = $item;
}
```

The above produces an assoc array with the letter as key - and put all none-alpha items in other

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the Laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models

```
$listing = App\Store::where('first_letter', 'a')
               ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
               ->take(10)
               ->get();
```

If you need something more specific, you can always create `Scopes` and use those in your eloquent models.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes